# Trim axis left in style

Tags: pgfplots

Why`trim axis left` doesn't work in style command ?

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

    \pgfplotsset{%
        compat=newest,
        axeseul/.style={%
        tick style={thin,black},
        axis x line = center,   % rien en y     
        axis y line = none,     % sans axe y
        ymin=0,ymax=0,          % sinon problème
        xmin=0,xmax=1,          % le plus fréquent
        trim axis left,         % pour l'alignement à gauche des axes
                                % page 317 pgfplots doc
        }}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axeseul,xmin=-3,xmax=2]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsset{%
        tick style={thin,black},
        axis x line = center,   % rien en y     
        axis y line = none,     % sans axe y
        ymin=0,ymax=0,          % sinon problème
        xmin=0,xmax=1,          % le plus fréquent
        trim axis left,         % pour l'alignement à gauche des axes
                                % page 317 pgfplots doc
        }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,xmax=2]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`trim axis left` needs to be supplied to the `tikzpicture` environment that contains the axis, not the `axis` environment. If you put it in a style that is supplied to the `axis` environment, it's called too late.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

    \pgfplotsset{%
        compat=newest,
        axeseul/.style={%
        tick style={thin,black},
        axis x line = center,   % rien en y     
        axis y line = none,     % sans axe y
        ymin=0,ymax=0,          % sinon problème
        xmin=0,xmax=1,          % le plus fréquent
        trim axis left,         % pour l'alignement à gauche des axes
                                % page 317 pgfplots doc
        }}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[axeseul,xmin=-3,xmax=2]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsset{%
        tick style={thin,black},
        axis x line = center,   % rien en y     
        axis y line = none,     % sans axe y
        ymin=0,ymax=0,          % sinon problème
        xmin=0,xmax=1,          % le plus fréquent
        trim axis left,         % pour l'alignement à gauche des axes
                                % page 317 pgfplots doc
        }

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,xmax=2]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems logical !